# Bind comments to my entites in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I´am just in the beginning of creating a comment system for my website. I´am using EF and I want to bind a few of my tables to the Comments table. We can say that I have a Car entity and a Bike entity in two separate tables, and I would like to bind a collection of comments of these two tables.

In my mind I have a picture that the comments table would contain:

```
CommentID | EntityID | CommentText

      1        Bike_2    Hello world..

      2         Car_2         -- 

      3        Bike_3         --
```

Am I thinking right? How do a setup this with entity framework?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The following is for Entity Framework 4.1 to 4.3.1 and Code-First/`DbContext`.)

The type of mapping which comes closest to your idea is [Table-per-Type (TPT) inheritance mapping](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx). It would look like this:

```
public abstract class EntityWithComments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public EntityWithComments Entity { get; set; }
}

public class Car : EntityWithComments
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Bicycle : EntityWithComments
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public bool HasThreeWheels { get; set; }
}
```

`EntityWithComments` is a base class for `Car` and `Bicycle` and perhaps other entities. Then you have a derived `DbContext` class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EntityWithComments> EntitiesWithComments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .ToTable("Cars");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bicycle>()
            .ToTable("Bicycles");
    }
}
```

As a result you have four tables in the database:

- A `Comments` table which looks like your proposal but `EntityId` won't refer directly to the `Cars` and `Bicycles` tables. Instead it refers to the base type table `EntitiesWithComments`.
- A table `EntitiesWithComments` representing the abstract base class and which only has a single column, namely the `Id` column.
- A table `Cars` with a one-to-one shared primary key constraint between the `Id` and the `Id` in table `EntitiesWithComments`
- A table `Bicycles` with a one-to-one shared primary key constraint between the `Id` and the `Id` in table `EntitiesWithComments`

You can then - for example - load all blue cars:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var blueCars = ctx.EntitiesWithComments.OfType<Car>()
        .Where(c => c.Color == "Blue")
        .ToList();
}
```

Because the `EntitiesWithComments` base table does not contain any column except the `Id` there is no join between the tables necessary. The generated SQL looks like this and only touches the table for the derived type:

```sql
SELECT 
'0X0X' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Manufacturer] AS [Manufacturer], 
[Extent1].[Color] AS [Color]
FROM [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'Blue' = [Extent1].[Color]
```

(I guess, the strange `0X0X` value in this query is kind of a type descriptor EF uses to check if the returned rows are really cars, but I am not sure.)

If you want to load all bicycles with three wheels including their comments the following query works:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var bicyclesWithThreeWheelsWithComments = ctx.EntitiesWithComments
        .Include(e => e.Comments)
        .OfType<Bicycle>()
        .Where(b => b.HasThreeWheels)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn´t now any of this strategies in EF, and now i´am aware of the thrre mappings strategies, TPH, TPT and TPC, thanks! I also have to admit that maybe this idea is´nt so good at all for my scenario, and that´s why you told that this one was the closest of my idea :)